# DVDfab encoding error

Tags: video, encoding, dvdfab

I'm trying to use the DVD ripper that comes with DVDfab 8.1 to encode `.mp4` video with single pass. I selected the first chapter, which is about 2 minutes long.

When the conversion starts and gets around 18%, I get the following error:

```
Work 1 failed, Error = 504.00 0 error: process exception, filter(type128:id11), info = 503.00 13
```

Does anyone have any idea what is causing  this error?

Answer (score 0):

1. Stop using DvdFab
2. Rip with http://www.makemkv.com
3. Encode with http://handbrake.fr

Answer (score 0):

It may be too late but I had the same issue and solve it by cutting a few seconds at the begining of the sequence (1 to 5 max), in DVDfab, of course :-)

Pieyrot